# Syntax error: "(" unexpected on shell script

Tags: shell, centos, ubuntu-12.04

I'm getting `7: Syntax error: "(" unexpected` error while running bellow code on Ubuntu. But It's run on centos without any issues.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
TODATE=`date '+%Y-%b-%d'`
#
# Backup Creation for Databases
#
databases=(`echo 'show databases;' | mysql -u root -ppaSSword | grep -v ^Database$`)
for DB in "${databases[@]}"; do
mysqldump --force --opt --user=root --password=paSSword $DB | gzip > /mnt/Backup/DB/${DB}_${TODATE}.sql.gz
done
#
```

Please help me to solve this.

I can't figure out problem. But,

I'm using bellow code for backup. It's working fine with Ubuntu

```
#!/bin/bash
#
TODATE=`date '+%Y-%b-%d'`
databases="$(mysql -u root -ppaSSword -Bse 'show databases')"
for DB in $databases
do
mysqldump -u root -psqlMYadmin $DB | gzip > /mnt/Backup/DB/${DB}_${TODATE}.sql.gz
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the 'show databases' output to dump.txt file, if done then try.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 da=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
 for db in `cat dump.txt` ; do mysqldump --force --opt --user=root --password=paSSword $db | gzip /path/to/backup/$db_"$da".sql.gz ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the last '$' on the line databases= ...

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `(` in the script and you have the shebang line `#!/bin/sh`. My best guess is that the program `/bin/sh` does not recognize array assignment, whereas `/bin/bash` would.

Change your shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.

You'd probably do better to use `$(...)` in place of the back ticks.)  Also, as [Sami Laine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2845360/sami-laine) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783681/15168), it would be better if you quoted the regex to the `grep` command (though it is not the cause of your problem):

```
databases=( $(echo 'show databases;' | mysql -u root -ppaSSword | grep -v '^Database$') )
```